# UglifyJS append files without removing whitespace

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, minify, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs

I'm using [UglifyJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) to mangle and compress the JavaScript code of my SPA. 
This is ok for production, however I'd like to just append all the JS files when compiling in debug mode.

I tried omitting the `-c` `-m` options (compress & mangle) but it didn't work, it just keep compressing and mangling the source files

I'd like to avoid using another tool or even worst writing my own to just append a set of JavaScript files

**EDIT**

test0.js input file:

```
var test1 = 0;
var test2 = 1;
var test3 = test1 + test2;
```

test1.js input file:

```
var test4 = 0;
var test5 = 1;
var test6 = test4 + test5;
```

command I run (no mangling nor compression specified):

> uglifyjs test0.js test1.js -o out.js

output I get:

```
var test1=0;var test2=1;var test3=test1+test2;var test4=0;var test5=1;var test6=test4+test5;
```

output I would expect:

```
var test1 = 0;
var test2 = 1;
var test3 = test1 + test2;
var test4 = 0;
var test5 = 1;
var test6 = test4 + test5;
```

I can confirm UglifyJS is stripping out all the CR/LF bytes from the files, I'd like to avoid that

[image]

Comment: UglifyJS shouldn't touch source files... It takes one or more JS files as input, then it wirtes an output file (as specified by the `-o` flag)

Comment: Can you try to reduce your issue to a minimal example that showcases the issue? e.g. create two js files with minimal content, run uglify over them and show the results? This will helpt troubleshooting the issue

Comment: @F.P I've done it, please have a look

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Are you using Uglify without something like Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your example we can see that uglify does in fact neither mangle nor comporess your code. It simply removes whitespace.

This happens because (as most things that handle code on a meta-level) your code is parsed to an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). This is an abstract represenation of your source code that **only contains actual commands**.

This means any formatting is lost as more or less the very first step that uglify does and there is no way to recover it.

See also [this issue](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1520). The better way to achieve traceability when developing is by using source maps, which uglify can generate with the `--source-map` option.

This will create a separate file `.map` that lives beside your uglified file and contains the information about which line contains what code.

Comment: that makes sense, ok I'll go for the .map file

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini It appears newer versions also offer a `--beautify` option that will essentially "reindent" your code when outputting it. But you will never get the original file endings or spaces back. But source maps are still the industry standard and best way to go.